# Multiple Date Select with three states of selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a requirement to build a calendar control that when the user clicks a date it toggles through three possible states with each click: All Day/AM/PM.

So when the user clicks the date for the first time the state of the date clicked will be "All Day", a second click with result in the state of "AM", the third click "PM" and the fourth will result in the date no longer being selected.

Any suggestions would be a great help.

I've tried the OBOUT ASP.NET controls but I can't quite get it to work how I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent the day developing my own custom control. Thanks for those that took the time to look and more thanks to those for suggestions.